# How do I scan for an INT value in another process memory

Tags: c++, windows, virtual-memory

I have been trying to find a good way to scan another programs memory on a specific value (int). What I have now does work but I am sure there are way better ways and way faster ways.

```
DWORD pid;
DWORD Money = 0x04661128; //Address of money in-game
int MyMoney;
int MyMoneyReal;

int main()
{
    HWND hWnd = FindWindowA(0, ("Euro Truck Simulator 2"));
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pid);
    HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);
    cout << "Please input your exact current money value!" << pid << endl;
    cin >> MyMoneyReal;
    for (int i = 0; i < 0x7FFFFFFF; i++) {
        ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)i, &MyMoney, sizeof(MyMoney), 0);
        if (MyMoney == MyMoneyReal) {
            cout << "Found a match: " << MyMoney << MyMoneyReal << " With HEX value: " << hex << i << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "Processing...";
}
```

So as you can see, I make an int MyMoney and MyMoneyReal. Then I proceed to scan from 0 to 0x7FFFFFFF in the program memory to find all addressess containing MyMoneyReal.
This takes a very long time to complete and I'm sure there are better ways, I have no clue how though.

I should add: I am very new to C++ so any extra help is always nice :)

Comment: Yes, that is slow.  Read bigger chunks of memory, then parse that.

Comment: You can use VirtualQueryEx to find out which parts of memory are in use, that will save you a lot of time too.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop calls `ReadProcessMemory` 2147483647 times.

Every time it's called it has to verify that the memory is readable and then it copies `sizeof(int)` bytes into the buffer. It has its cost...

You can read for example 1MB chunks of memory so you've got fewer calls to `ReadProcessMemory`. Then you can process each chunk locally just like you do it now. Simplified version:

```
constexpr unsigned CHUNK_SIZE = 0x100000;
constexpr unsigned MAX_ADDRESS = 0x7FFFFFFF;
//remember to make sure stack is big enough or allocate it on heap
char buffer[CHUNK_SIZE];

for (unsigned i = 0; i < MAX_ADDRESS; i += CHUNK_SIZE) {
    if (ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)i, buffer, sizeof(buffer), nullptr)) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= CHUNK_SIZE - sizeof(int); ++j) {
            int something;
            memcpy(&something, buffer + j, sizeof(int));
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the inner `for` we read up until `CHUNK_SIZE - sizeof(int)` because we don't want to read past the end of buffer. However outer loop in my example doesn't handle it properly and we skip some bytes. It's easy to fix, I leave it up to you.

Of course your buffer can be bigger/smaller. You have to try and measure.

**Note:** This is still a lot of operations. We just limit the number of calls to potentially expensive `ReadProcessMemory`. You should try to limit your address range. I'm pretty sure most of this calls to `ReadProcessMemory` just fail. As suggested in comments, one is to use [VirtualQueryEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366907.aspx)

Comment: How do I get the value with the address of the ram from it?

Comment: @PauldeKoning treat `i` as base and `j` as offset. So `i + j`